# Erase a boundRect in opencv 3.0 C++

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I am finding an object in a image using contourns. and I am enclose the possibles cadidates in boundRects for see the final result, I want remove the finals recangles where the height > width (enclose it in the black circles). Any suggestion for to do this. Thanks thanks for your Help and response. My code is:

```
enter vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly(contours.size());
            vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());

            for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
            {
                approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true);
                boundRect[i] = boundingRect(Mat(contours_poly[i]));
            }
             for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
            {
                Scalar color = Scalar(255, 0, 255);
                rectangle(result_white, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0);
                rectangle(imageLoad, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0);
            }
            imshow("white final", imageLoad);
```

and tthe final result is: 
[final image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GULbq.png)

Comment: What do you mean with remove? If you want to remove the image content at that point, you could create a mask and apply this mask to the image.

Comment: Thanks for  your comment, i want erase the contours inside of the boundRect generated.

Comment: And with "erase" you mean what?

Comment: mean that those areas don't represents a good result for me. So, the only thing that i want is discard those areas end choose the only region interest for me that is the Rect where the heigh < width. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, then you can draw the countours in the color of your background (or any other color you like) to get rid of them. use `drawContours` and the flag `CV_FiILLED`.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer @PSchn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why remove them?

Just not append them to vector of rectangles if it not fit your requrements (use push_back for vector).

Comment: Thanks for  your comment, i want erase the contours inside of the boundRect generated.

Comment: Then draw rectangles filled with background color.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer @Andrey Smorodov